# PostgreSQL - Trigger after import

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a database with two tables, A and B. A is much bigger than B.

From some specific criteria, I have a view built from records from table A. Let's call it V<sub>a</sub>.

A second view, V<sub>V<sub>a</sub>-B</sub>, is the difference bewteen records which are on V<sub>a</sub> and B (all the records on V<sub>a</sub> that are not in B). V<sub>a</sub> is greater or equal size than B.

Both tables, A and B, have the same column structure, except by one, a serial number. The data is loaded to those tables through import from a CSV file. There is a column which fills automatically the date when each record has been created. The imports should be on a monthly basis.

**The problem:** I need to update the records of table A which exist in V<sub>V<sub>a</sub>-B</sub>, recently created (that is, after importing new data in A and B) and have some field as NULL (I guess it doesn't matter which). The trigger function should look if each recently created element of V<sub>V<sub>a</sub>-B</sub> has an exact copy in the previous month. If it has, the value of the field should be copied from the old record to the new. If not, some predefined value is written.

Because V<sub>V<sub>a</sub>-B</sub> depends both on A and B, I don't know where to put the trigger. If I put it on A, the view will not have all the data yet. If I put it on B, how can I assure that it doesn't repeat more than once per import? Will it be a better idea just using an stored procedure (function) manually?

Thank you.

EDIT: added "each recently created element" for clarification, the trigger has not to cycle through all the records in V<sub>V<sub>a</sub>-B</sub> every time, just the recently added ones.

Comment: NULL is not a value, so it cannot be a value for a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write a trigger that changes the necessary record(s) in A whenever a row in A (or B) has been modified, you can write a trigger (or two) to perform the operation. The views will reflect changes in the tables immediately, if that's your concern.

But this solution is only commendable if the trigger function is not expensive – it will execute for each modified row.

If you cannot easily write a simple trigger function that does the trick, the better solution is to introduce a post-processing step run after A and B have been modified.